# store argv[1] to an char variable

Tags: c, argv

I pass a character to my program and I want to store this character to variable. For example I run my program like this `./a.out s file`. Now I want to save the argv[1] (its the s) to a variable (lets say I define it like this `char ch;`. I saw this approach:

```
ch = argv[1][0];
```

and it works. But I cant understand it. The array argv isnt a one dimensional array? if i remove the [0], I get a warning `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: "The array argv isnt a one dimensional array?" - no: `char *argv[]` -- it's a pointer-to-pointer. (You can think of it as a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers-to-`char`).

Comment: In C, difference between an array and a pointer may seem a bit hazy. Pointer can always be interpreted as pointer to first element of array and indexed with [], and argv[1] gives pointer to char, so another [] can be added to use it as char array (which is what it really is in this case, too).

Comment: Ok i understood it. I read this http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html and it says that  `argv is a one-dimensional array of strings`. thats why I thought it was a one dimensional.

Comment: C has two kinds of arrays of strings: 1-dimensional array of char pointers (each pointing to array of char, can even be same one, and pointer can be NULL too), and 2-dimensional array of char (each row is string with max length of row size). Array of pointers is more common, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of `main()` you see that it's

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv);
```

or

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);
```

So `argv` is an array of `const char *` (i.e. character pointers or "C strings").  If you dereference `argv[1]` you'll get:

```
"s"
```

or:

```
{ 's' , '\0' }
```

and if you dereference `argv[1][0]`, you'll get:

```
's'
```

As a side note, there is no need to copy that character from `argv[1]`, you could simply do:

```
const char *myarg = NULL;

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: myprog myarg\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (strlen(argv[1]) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    myarg = argv[1];

    // Use argument as myarg[0] from now on

}
```

Comment: how will you convert char * argv[] to char variable and char [] variable

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal Start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

`argv` is an array of strings, or say, an array of `char *`. So the type of `argv[1]` is `char *`, and the type of `argv[1][0]` is `char`.

Answer (score 2):

The typical declaration for `argv` is

```
char* argv[]
```

That is an array of `char*`. Now `char*` itself is, here, a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`.

So, `argv[1]` is of type `char*`, which is an array. So you need another application of the `[]` operator to get an element of that array, of type `char`.

Comment: what? it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

Lets see mains' signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

No, `argv` is not a one-dimensional array. Its is a two-dimensional char array.

1. `argv[1]` returns char*
2. `argv[1][0]` returns the first char in in `argv[1]`